# How to print the list in one line with delimiter?

Tags: c#, .net

I am fetching data form the web using [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23). Some information are in list. While fetching the data it shows like this.

```
Notre Dame Academy2.25 km       
VIBGYOR High School1.43 km      
St.Peter's School1.72 km        
The Amaatra Academy0.65 km      
Aurinko Academy1.41 km      
Little Elly First Step1.22 km
```

This is my code.

```
string PropertyFeatures = browserInstance.Div(Find.ByClass("amentities-icons")).OuterText;
```

In `Excel` it shows multiple lines. I want in one line with some delimiter like `,` or `|`. 
my expected output is like this:

> Notre Dame Academy2.25 km|VIBGYOR High School1.43 km|St.Peter's School1.72 km.

It fetches the above result.

Comment: i am fetching data from the web.but i don't know how to align the list once we received.

Comment: Do you want a concatenated string ?

Comment: yes some what.my problem is the output is in list.i dont know how to align in one line with some delimiter

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
string DelimitString(string inputStr, string delimiter, char splitChar = '\n')
{
    return string.Join(delimiter, inputStr.Split(splitChar));
}
```

**Call..**

```
MessageBox.Show(DelimitString("Hi\nMy\nName\nIs\nMick", "|"));
```

**Output..**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try adding replace to your code::

```
string PropertyFeatures = browserInstance.Div(
                             Find.ByClass("amentities-icons")
                          ).OuterText.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, ", ")
```

You can read more about [Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method and [NewLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in MSDN.